# Accessing function of delegate in GridView

Tags: qml

I have a GridView which uses a DelegateModel as its model:

```
GridView{
    function test(idx) {
       model.items.get(idx).testFunction()
    }
    model: DelegateModel{
        id: visualModel
        model: myModel
        delegate: myItem {}
    }
}
```

How can I call a function of the delegate or set a property of the delegate if I know its index?

E.g. if I try to call the function `test` I get the error

`TypeError: Property 'testFunction' of object [object Object] is not a function`

I don't understand this. Here the top of my delegate

```
Item {
  id: delegateRoot
  function testFunction() {
    console.log("success")
  }
```

So is the `model.items.get(idx)` line wrong? Also, how can I check/debug whether this actually gave me the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function on the model. But it is in the view's delegate, therefore it can not be found.

Ad hoc I don't know a solution on how to get the delegate from the view. The problem here is, that it might be, that the delegate has not even been created at the time where you try to call it.

For a `Repeater` you could easily call `itemAt(index)` to fetch it - since the `Repeater` always instantiates delegates for everything in the model.

Most likely you want to refactor, so that the function is no member of the delegate anymore, but works just by taking the model data (which you can retrieve as from the model via `get`) and manipulate the delegate through the roles in the model.

You could e.g. have a role 'trigger'. You connect in the delegate your function to the changed-signal, and increment that trigger in the model, when ever you want to call your function.